# Right usage of Qt5 elements regarding memory management

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5, smart-pointers

I have the following common scenario:

```
class A : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(QWidget *parent=0);
private:
    QFormLayout *m_formLayout;
    QLinedEdit *m_lineEditTest;
};

A::A(QWidget *parent)
{
    m_formLayout = new QFormLayout(ui.widget_Test);
    m_formLayout->setMargin(0);
    m_formLayout->setSpacing(0);

    m_lineEditTest = new QLineEdit();
    m_formLayout->addWidget(m_lineEditTest);

    ui.widget_Test->setLayout(m_formLayout);
}

A::~A()
{
    delete m_lineEditTest, m_formLayout;
}
```

Is this the correct approach to use class member variables for Qt GUI elements and delete them after the destruction of the QDialog A?

Why I'm asking: I want to avoid raw pointers in my application and replace it with smart pointers, <s>but it's not recommended to use Qt5 with e.g. std::shared_ptr</s>! So should I use https://wiki.qt.io/Smart_Pointers and if yes which one for my scenario? Thx

Comment: Qt has build-in mechanism of `QObjects` destruction if you properly set their parent-child relationship. As docs say: "The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its destructor. ". There are plenty of discussions on this topic. For example: https://forum.qt.io/topic/65443/raw-pointers-in-qt/2 .

Comment: Especially for GUI object, parent-child relationships is the way to go, but using smart pointers for it should not give any problem. Why do you think `std::shared_ptr` is not recommended? It is true that it may be less portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a summary: (from https://forum.qt.io/topic/65443/raw-pointers-in-qt/5)

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent = nullptr) {
        obj1 = new QObject(this); // Sets the parent using the 'parent' constructor parameter

        obj2 = new QObject;
        obj2->setParent(this); // Sets the parent using QObject::setParent()

        obj3 = new QObject; // No parent
    }

private:
    QObject *obj1;
    QObject *obj2;
    QObject *obj3;
};
```

When you delete your `MyObject`, it will automatically delete `obj1` and `obj2` because of the parent-child relationship. However, `obj3` will not get deleted because you did not set it as a child, so the memory for `obj3` gets leaked.

There are many ways to handle deletions:

- do it manually
- use smart pointers
- use QObject's parent-child system

So there is no problem to use smart pointers with Qt5 if you don't mix it with parent-child system!

Comment: The problem may occur when you combine two of the mentioned approaches. For example, if you declare `std::unique_ptr<QObject> obj1;` in your example.